# Ideas on getting rid of boiler plate code

Tags: c++, c++11, reflection, macros

My problem is very specific. I have the following requirement, I need to set member variables that exist in child class from parent class, for several reasons. My plan is to pass a function pointer of the setter method (which exist in child class), that takes string as argument, to the parent class at construction. The parent class defines a public method that takes member name and value string as argument and invokes the function pointer of the member with value string. The parent class can exist in a dll or lib and have no access to any conversion or factory methods, so the setter method have to be defined in child class.

Since the parent can be a base class for other classes, i wrote some macros shown as below:

```
#define DEFINE_VAL(Type, memberName) \
        private: \
            Type memberName; \
            void set##memberName(std::string const& val) { \
                memberName = convert_to_val(val); /* this will be a call to factory which converts string to value type*/\
/* or call to local implementation for conversion*/
            }; \

#define INIT_VAL(memberName) \
            { memberName, \
            [&](std::string const& val) { set##memberName(val); }}
```

Parent and child classes are as below:

```
// parent.h probably in dll
class parent
{
public:
    parent(std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string const&)>>& m)
        : m(m)
    { }
        ... 
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string const&)>> m;
};

// child.h
class child : public parent
{
public:
    child() : parent({ INIT_VAL(iVal), ... })
    { }
private:
    DEFINE_VAL(int, iVal);
        ...
};
```

The child class can have many variables defined and its a bit annoying to first use DEFINE_VAL macro and then pass each variable's setter method with INIT_VAL macro. Can this be done in one macro (probably in DEFINE_VAL)? or any ideas on automatic registration of member name and function pointer to parent class?

I would also appreciate any alternative ideas on accomplishing my requirement.

Comment: is this a placeholder or really `...` in `parent({ INIT_VAL(iVal), ... })` ?

Comment: it is less boilerplate if you simply do not use a macro but instead write `child() : member( convert_to_value(iVal) ) {}` ...

Comment: What you want is not really possible in the current form of your code. You can get rid of the macro by using functions instead, but that's it. Being only able to specify the map in the constructor of `parent` is very restrictive, and using named members is even more because there are no type introspection in C++.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 If you don't use macro, you will have to at least have something like `convert_to_value("iVal", iVal)`.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Its not an ellipsis operator, if thats what your question is. I just want show that there can be more such INIT_VAL macro calls in there. I should have mentioned in the question, I cannot simply pass factory function pointer to parent class since the child class can provide its own implementation for string to val type conversions. This allows us to provide local implementations for some types that are not available globally.

Comment: @Holt I am open for major structural changes as long it satisfies my requirement.

Comment: @PVRT I am not suggesting to pass a factory function pointer to parent class, but I am suggesting to pass the already converted value. Why does it need to be passed via the base class anyhow? Dont you simply initialize a member of the child class?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The child class is not allowed to change its member values by itself because its part of a scheduler framework. The child can modify its member value only via the base class (for synchronization and lot of other things). Just initialization of child member is not enough as they can be changed with user interaction.

Comment: sorry I dont really understand...  "The child class is not allowed to change its member values by itself" .. but your macro just expands to the child class calling its own setter to set the value. You say "I need to set member variables that exist in child class from parent class" but your current solution is not doing that, unless I miss something. It is the child class  setting the value and if that is the case then I dont see the need for the macro

Comment: ah I am starting to understand. FOr some reason it Is essential that the child only passes the function pointer that later will be called by the parent... but why? Can you clarify? Or is this what your last comment refers to? Later on you will get strings and need the function pointer in the base to call it?

Comment: _"I have the following requirement, I need to set member variables that exist in child class from parent class, for several reasons"_ Your requirement violates _all_ the tenets of OOP and that's why you are having difficulties. Don't fight the language!!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don’t think that’s what the OP really wants... This looks more like some generic way of exchanging / storing data structures, like if, e.g., `parent` was some kind of JSON interface, and then you extend it so that you can read and write it. I am not the OP, so I may be wrong but this very much looks like this.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 my last comment refers to your question. It is also true later on i will get values only as strings.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to set member variables that exist in child class from parent class, for several reasons. My plan is to pass a function pointer of the setter method (which exist in child class), that takes string as argument, **to the parent class at construction**.

When parent class constructor is invoked the derived class and its members have not been initialized yet and, pedantically, they do not exist yet. For this reason, it is not possible to set derived class members from its base class constructor.

---

One solution is to use a virtual function to set members by name.

Without built-in reflection in current C++, to associate names with data members and generate member accessors the best practice is still to use macros. One of the best macros for this purpose is [`BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Struct.html).

`boost::lexical_cast<T>` can be used to convert from `std::string` to any `T`.

A working example with deep and multiple inheritance support:

```
#include <boost/hana/define_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/accessors.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/concat.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/length.hpp>

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct MemberSetter {
    // Using void* to reduce the number of template instantiations.
    using SetterFn = std::function<void(void*, std::string const&)>;
    using Setters = std::unordered_map<std::string, SetterFn>;

    Setters setters_;

    template<class Derived, class Accessors>
    MemberSetter(Derived* that, Accessors& accessors) {
        hana::for_each(accessors, [this](auto const& pair) {
            auto setter = [accessor = hana::second(pair)](void* vthat, std::string const& value) {
                auto* that = static_cast<Derived*>(vthat);
                auto& member = accessor(*that);
                member = boost::lexical_cast<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(member)>>(value);
            };
            auto name = hana::first(pair);
            setters_.emplace(std::string(hana::to<char const*>(name), hana::length(name)), std::move(setter));
        });
    }

    bool findAndSetMember(void* that, std::string const& name, std::string const& value) const {
        auto setter = setters_.find(name);
        if(setter != setters_.end()) {
            (setter->second)(that, value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual bool setMember(std::string const& name, std::string const& value) = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(B,
        (int, a),
        (double, b)
        );

    bool setMember(std::string const& name, std::string const& value) override {
        constexpr auto accessors = hana::accessors<B>();
        static MemberSetter const setter(this, accessors);
        return setter.findAndSetMember(this, name, value);
    }
};

struct C : B {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(C,
        (std::string, c)
        );

    bool setMember(std::string const& name, std::string const& value) override {
        constexpr auto accessors = hana::concat(hana::accessors<B>(), hana::accessors<C>()); // Join with members of the base class.
        static MemberSetter const setter(this, accessors);
        return setter.findAndSetMember(this, name, value);
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.setMember("a", "1");
    c.setMember("b", "2.3");
    c.setMember("c", "hello");
    std::cout << c.a << ' ' << c.b << ' ' << c.c << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 2.3 hello
```

Comment: I don’t think OP want to initialize variable of the derived class in the base class constructor... This is not mentioned in the question at least. What OP wants is to provide to parent a way to set elements of the derived class, likely after full construction of the object.

Comment: Just to clarify, I meant, i am passing the function pointers of the child class setter methods to the parent class at construction. You raised good point though.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a virtual function to set it, and move the map to the child as it really should be an implementation detail. This way the parent class doesn't really have anything to do with how the members are set.

```
class parent
{
public:
    virtual ~parent() = default;
protected:
    virtual void do_set(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) = 0;
private:
    void set(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) {
        do_set(name, value);
        // Do synchronization here
    }
};

class child : public parent
{
protected:
    void do_set(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) override {
        child::setter_map.at(name)(*this, value);
    }
private:
    int iVal;

    static const std::map<std::string, void(*)(child&, const std::string&)> setter_map;
};

#define INIT_VAL(NAME, ...) { #NAME, [](child& c, const std::string& value) __VA_ARGS__ }

const std::map<std::string, void(*)(child&, const std::string&)> child::setter_map = {
    INIT_VAL(iVal, {
      c.iVal = convert_to_val(value);
    }),
    // Init other members
};
```

And from this, you might be able to find a better way to implement `set` (Maybe a simple `if (name == ...) ... else if (name == ...) ...` would work)

Or if you don't want to use runtime polymorphism, at least don't store a map in every instance of `parent`. Store a reference to a global map (Which would be like a vtable itself):

```
class parent
{
public:
    parent() = delete;
protected:
    using setter_map = std::map<std::string, void(*)(parent&, const std::string&)>;
    parent(const setter_map& child_smap) noexcept : smap(&child_smap) {};
private:
    void set(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) {
        smap->at(name)(*this, value);
        // Do synchronization here
    }

    const setter_map* smap;
};

class child : public parent {
public:
    child() : parent(smap) {};
private:
    int iVal;

    static const setter_map smap;
};

#define INIT_VAL(NAME, ...) { #NAME, \
    [](parent& _c, const std::string& value) { \
        child& c = static_cast<child&>(_c); \
        __VA_ARGS__ \
    } \
}

const child::setter_map child::smap = {
    INIT_VAL(iVal, {
        c.iVal = convert_to_val(value);
    }),
    // (Other member setters here)
};

#undef INIT_VAL

// Or having the setters inside the class, like in your original code

class child2 : public parent {
public:
    child2() : parent(smap) {};
private:
    int iVal;
    void set_iVal(const std::string& value) {
        iVal = convert_to_val(value);
    }

    // Using a macro (Probably don't need the macros here, writing out a setter is more clear)
    template<class T>
    using type = T;
#define DEFINE_VAL(TYPE, NAME, ...) \
    void set_ ## NAME (const std::string& value) { \
        __VA_ARGS__ \
    } \
    type<TYPE> NAME

    DEFINE_VAL(float, fVal, {
        fVal = convert_val_to_float(value);
    });

    DEFINE_VAL(char[2], charArrVal, {
        charArrVal[0] = value[0];
        charArrVal[1] = value[1];
    });

    static const setter_map smap;
};

#define INIT_VAL(NAME) { #NAME, [](parent& p, const std::string& value) { static_cast<child2&>(p).set_ ## NAME (value); } }
const child2::setter_map child2::smap = {
    INIT_VAL(iVal), INIT_VAL(fVal), INIT_VAL(charArrVal)
};
#undef INIT_VAL

// Or if `convert_to_val(value)` is literally the body of every setter, that simplifies the `INIT_VAL` macro

class child3 : public parent {
public:
    child3() : parent(smap) {};
private:
    int iVal;

    static const setter_map smap;
};

#define INIT_VAL(NAME) { #NAME, [](parent& p, const std::string& value) { static_cast<child3&>(p). NAME = convert_to_val(value); } }

const child3::setter_map child3::smap = {
    INIT_VAL(iVal)
};
```